# Discord.py turning a text into an embed (with pages)

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm going to need some help with this, as I don't understand it.
I have a code which turns the page of what the bots says through reactions, the code is below:

```py
client.command()
async def help2(ctx):
    contents = ["This is page 1!", "This is page 2!", "This is page 3!", "This is page 4!"]
    pages = 4
    cur_page = 1
    message = await ctx.send(f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n{contents[cur_page-1]}")
    # getting the message object for editing and reacting

    await message.add_reaction("◀️")
    await message.add_reaction("▶️")

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["◀️", "▶️"]
        # This makes sure nobody except the command sender can interact with the "menu"

    while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=check)
            # waiting for a reaction to be added - times out after x seconds, 60 in this
            # example

            if str(reaction.emoji) == "▶️" and cur_page != pages:
                cur_page += 1
                await message.edit(content=f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n{contents[cur_page-1]}")
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

            elif str(reaction.emoji) == "◀️" and cur_page > 1:
                cur_page -= 1
                await message.edit(content=f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n{contents[cur_page-1]}")
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

            else:
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
                # removes reactions if the user tries to go forward on the last page or
                # backwards on the first page
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.delete()
            break
            # ending
```

So this is the code, however I want to make it an embed that can be used as a help page with reactions (setfooter and author too)!
Sorry as I'm new at this!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly good at python either but I found this worked for me:

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", help_command = None)
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    pages = 4
    cur_page = 1
    contents = ["This is page 1!", "This is page 2!", "This is page 3!", "This is page 4!"]
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Help page", description=(f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n{contents[cur_page-1]}"), color=0x00ffc8)
    embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name,icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text="footer")
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    # getting the message object for editing and reacting

    await message.add_reaction("◀️")
    await message.add_reaction("▶️")

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["◀️", "▶️"]
        # This makes sure nobody except the command sender can interact with the "menu"

    while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=check)
            # waiting for a reaction to be added - times out after x seconds, 60 in this
            # example

            if str(reaction.emoji) == "▶️" and cur_page != pages:
                cur_page += 1
                new_embed=discord.Embed(title="Help page", description=(f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n{contents[cur_page-1]}"), color=0x00ffc8)
                new_embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name,icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                new_embed.set_footer(text="footer")
                await message.edit(embed=new_embed)
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

            elif str(reaction.emoji) == "◀️" and cur_page > 1:
                cur_page -= 1
                new_embed=discord.Embed(title="Help page", description=(f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}:\n{contents[cur_page-1]}"), color=0x00ffc8)
                new_embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name,icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                new_embed.set_footer(text="footer")
                await message.edit(embed=new_embed)
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

            else:
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
                # removes reactions if the user tries to go forward on the last page or
                # backwards on the first page
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.delete()
            break
            # ending
```

Comment: It would be better to explain what this code does instead of just copy pasting it.